# Changing images as service start

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm working with Android currently, coding in Eclipse.

I'm trying to set an image (pic1) in XML and this picture is replaced with another image (pic2) when a service is started(and reverts back when the service is stopped). Is this possible? (VERY new to this..) I realize i can set an image and how, I just can't find an answer to how to make the change between pic1 -> pic2. Help?

Thanks in advance, and I apologize if anything is unclear or just plain dumb.
-Bobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use two `ImageViews` for accomplishing this.

You can get the reference to your `ImageView` using the `findViewById` method of your current activity, and once you have it, you can change it's resource drawable (it will show the new image):

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.layout.connection_image);
if (serviceStarted)
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.started);
else
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopped);
```

Comment: Oh my, I'll try this right away! Expect a response within a few (hopefully) minutes!

Comment: glad to hear that, happy coding further! :)